# Create search query in Splunk through API (python code)

Tags: python, api, splunk, connection-refused

I am trying to do a search query in splunk through an API. I found a reference code on https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/RESTTUT/RESTsearches. I tried running the code on jupyter notebook.

But it gives a Connection refused error.

Code:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from future import standard_library
    standard_library.install_aliases()
    import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
    import httplib2
    from xml.dom import minidom

    baseurl = 'https://localhost:8089'
    userName = 'username'
    password = 'password'

    searchQuery = '| inputcsv foo.csv | where sourcetype=access_common | head 5'

    # Authenticate with server.
    # Disable SSL cert validation. Splunk certs are self-signed.
    serverContent = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True).request(baseurl +                         '/services/auth/login','POST', headers={}, body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'username':userName,         'password':password}))[1]

    sessionKey = minidom.parseString(serverContent).getElementsByTagName('sessionKey')        [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

    # Remove leading and trailing whitespace from the search
    searchQuery = searchQuery.strip()

    # If the query doesn't already start with the 'search' operator or another
    # generating command (e.g. "| inputcsv"), then prepend "search " to it.
    if not (searchQuery.startswith('search') or searchQuery.startswith("|")):
searchQuery = 'search ' + searchQuery

            print(searchQuery)

    # Run the search.
    # Again, disable SSL cert validation.
    print(httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True).request(baseurl +         '/services/search/jobs','POST',
        headers={'Authorization': 'Splunk %s' % sessionKey},body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'search': searchQuery}))[1]) '''
```

Error:

```
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` is thrown when your script cannot create a TCP connection to the server. Can you confirm using `telnet` that the server is running and is allowing connections on port `8089`. This doesn't look like a HTTP or permission issue, the error is for something lower in the stack.